# subtracting a 2D array from a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 3D array which contains a number of  2D arrays. I also have a 2D array. I want to subtract this 2D array from every element of the 3D array.
I did this (`BT_19` is the 3D array, `Avg_19` is the 2D array. `A` is the new array I created)

```
A=[]
for i in len(range(BT_19)):
   ref = BT_19[i]-Avg_19
   A = np.concatenate((A,[ref]),axis=0)
   print A
```

and then I got this error,

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-429b94e5b4d6> in <module>()
      1 A=[]
      2 abc=0
----> 3 for i in len(range(BT_19)):
      4     ref = BT_19[i]-Avg_19
      5     A = np.concatenate((A,[ref]),axis=0)

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: `len(range(BT_19))` should probably be `range(len(BT_19))` - looks like a mistype.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform the calculation using broadcasting concept of Numpy, since you have a 2D matrix, your operation (subtraction), will be broadcasted to the 3D matrix as follows:

```
In [1]: x = np.array([[1,1], [2,2]])
In [2]: x
Out[2]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
In [3]: y = np.random.randint(0,10, size=(5,2,2))

In [4]: y.shape
Out[4]: (5, 2, 2)

In [5]: y
Out[5]: 
array([[[3, 2],
        [4, 6]],

       [[9, 9],
        [5, 8]],

       [[0, 9],
        [5, 2]],

       [[6, 3],
        [9, 5]],

       [[5, 6],
        [5, 0]]])

In [6]: y - x
Out[6]: 
array([[[ 2,  1],
        [ 2,  4]],

       [[ 8,  8],
        [ 3,  6]],

       [[-1,  8],
        [ 3,  0]],

       [[ 5,  2],
        [ 7,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 3, -2]]])
```